# Force CPU full with display black

Tags: overclocking, cpu

i have a galaxy core duos and minergate instaled for test, however, my H/s in on display stay in 7 and in off stay in 0,5, i instaled overclock app however did not work.

how to force CPU full speedy in off display?

Samsung did this on a galaxys s3 rig

Comment: Disable `Doze`. Set Governor as 'Performance'. Set the highest value possible for low & high clock speed. You're done. And pity your battery.

Comment: disable doze? I'll study it, governor stay in performance, This cell phone is for testing only, no problem with battery

Answer (score 1):

You can force your cpu to work at full speed by changing the governor to Performance. If you are not sure what a governor is, you need to have ROOT ACCESS then you can use an app named Kernel Adiutor(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor&hl=en) to change the cpu governor.

Also, overclocking would require a custom kernel which you can find at XDA Forums.

Found these relevant guides:
Tomsguide:https://www.tomsguide.com/us/overclock-android-device,review-1762.html

Androidpit: https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-overclock-android

Comment: only with custon kernel? stock rom not working? I already put the governor in performance

Comment: Stock kernels don't allow(aren't built to support) overclocking.